# change variable value after click jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I want to be able to click on a canvas, move it to the map, drop it on the map. After dropping it on the map, they can select the canvas on the map and move it again. The process is repeated. I have trouble with the ignoreMouseMove variable, it does not reset to false and is always true.

Here is link to the demo: https://pokemon-map-electro2k.c9users.io/index.html

```
var moveCanvas = function ($canvas, e) {
    $(".map ul li." + $canvas).offset({
        left: e.pageX - 30,
        top: e.pageY - 30
    });
};

// When user first click on canvas
var onmousemove = function ($canvas) {

    var ignoreMouseMove = false;

    // Make canvas follow cursor in the map area
    $(".map").mousemove(function (e) {
        if (ignoreMouseMove) return;    // event handling mousemove is "disabled"
        moveCanvas($canvas, e);
    }).click(function () {

        // "re-enable" mousemove
        ignoreMouseMove = true;

        // When canvas is click on again within the map area, make canvas follow cursor
        $(".map ul li").click(function () {
            $(".map").mousemove(function (e) {
                if (!ignoreMouseMove) return;
                moveCanvas($canvas, e);
            }).click(function () {
                // Click function does not work anymore. ignoreMouseMove can't be reset. It is always true
                ignoreMouseMove = false; 
            })
        });

    });

};
```

Comment: Did you try `mouseup`  or `mousedown` instead?

Comment: yeah, but it's not really what I want. I want to click on the canvas, drop it on the map. Then the user can choose to click on the canvas on the map to change the location of the canvas

Comment: Still your can use `mousedown` for handling "pick up" and `mouseup` for "drop"

Comment: but you have to hold the mouse down for pick up. I want the image to follow the cursor freely without holding down the mouse then click again to drop

Answer (score 1):

You may need to change the below line

```
// "re-enable" mousemove
ignoreMouseMove = true;
```

in to

```
// "re-enable" mousemove
ignoreMouseMove = !ignoreMouseMove;
```

Comment: does the link work? The website has images. JSFiddle doesn't allow files to be uploaded

Comment: the link works, but I couldn't change and test, let me see